# How can I set up Thunderbird on my laptop to retrieve old emails from my home computer/server

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

Hi I'm running out of space (200GB) on my Gmail account and don't want to move up to 1TB. But I have emails back from 2009 when I first moved to Gmail. I don't always nee access to those old emails. But occasionally when I'm on the road, I may need to find something.

I'm looking for way to be able to run Thunderbird on my laptop that can access these old emails running off my home system shared drive (which I can remotely turn on).

Or some other similar solution. I'm not married to Tbird. But prefer that over Outlook as I've seen Outlook change formats and old Outlook emails stop working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Thunderbird to read the e-mails isn't going to free up space, unless you plan on downloading the e-mails onto your machine thus removing them from your Gmail quota. You are then going to have to implement a backup policy for your local mail file. Have you considered these actions?

Comment: Using Thunderbird to read the e-mails isn't going to free up space, unless you plan on downloading the e-mails onto your machine thus removing them from your Gmail quota. You are then going to have to implement a backup policy for your local mail file. Have you considered these actions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a client who wished to do the same thing, but after many attempts with many email clients, No email client exists that can cope reliably with 200gb of emails. Upgrading the gmail account is the easiest option.

Another method is using the standalone email archiver called [mailarchiva](https://www.mailarchiva.com/). It is free up to 10 email accounts and easily connects to gmail. This will download all your mail but you will need your own server.